# Can't Apply Property to CSS Style JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply a different width to my CSS style. When I have the `width` in the CSS file as `width: 100px;`, it draws both divs correctly, however, it does not correctly set the `width` when I use jQuery or change the HTML `width`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="details" class="hideClass transbox" style="overflow:auto;"></div>
<div id="details2" class="hideClass transbox" style="overflow:auto;"></div>
<div id="dDur" class="dDur"></div>
<div id="dDur2" class="dDur2"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
if(dur > 0 && maxDur > 0) {
    var newDur = ((1-(dur / maxDur)) * 60)+"px";
    var newDur2 = ((dur / maxDur) * 60)+"px";
    console.log(newDur + " dur " + newDur2) --> returns "58.5px dur 1.5px"

    $("#dDur").css({ width: newDur });
    $("#dDur2").css({ width: newDur2 });
    $("#").css({ border: '2px solid '+bonusColor });
    detailString += "<div class='dDur' width='"+newDur+"'></div>
    <div class='dDur2' width='"+newDur2+"'> </div>";
}
```

The lines at the bottom were used previously and did not work, they are not meant to be in the code.

Comment: what is "dur" and "maxDur"?

Comment: dur is "58.5px" maxDur is "1.5px"

Comment: i asked from where you getting this values please post full code !

Comment: dur and maxDur are a value between 100 and 120 and are the same, sorry I told you newDur and newDur2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `"<div class='dDur' width='"+newDur+"'></div>"` you should use `"<div class='dDur' style='width:"+newDur+";'></div>"`. Also, JS doesn't do well with multi-line strings and you should either escape or remove that line-break, or break it into two strings:

```
detailString += "<div class='dDur' style='width:"+newDur+";'></div>" +
    "<div class='dDur2' style='width:"+newDur2+";'></div>";
```

Also, what's this `$("#")` supposed to select?

Note that this:

```
$("#dDur").css({ width: newDur });
$("#dDur2").css({ width: newDur2 });
```

will only edit the styling of current elements, not ones you may add later with JS. If you're appending that `detailString` into your html, you should run the `$().css()` function after doing so.